# Spring Kafka concurrency with spring-integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I cannot tell if I'm missing something obvious, or there is a bug in `spring-integration-kafka:3.0.1` for trying to have multiple consumers running for a topic. The scenario is a single Kafka topic with 10 partitions, and a single springboot-app that listens to it. Relevant configuration is:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: test-consumer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    listener:
      concurrency: 4
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan("com.test")
public class MessageConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel testReceiveChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testReceiveFlow(@Qualifier("kafkaConsumerFactory") final ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumer, final MessageChannel testReceiveChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaConsumer, ListenerMode.record, "test-topic"))
                .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(EventMessage.class))
                .channel(testReceiveChannel)
                .get();
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
@Component
public class EventListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventListener.class);

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testReceiveChannel")
    public void processMessage(final EventMessage message) {
        LOG.info("Got message {} on {}", message.getValue(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

When started, I only get 1 container listening on all 10 partitions. I can see that `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` has the proper concurrency value set on it, but it appears it's `initializeContainer` method is never called (which would apply it to the actual consumer, if I understand it correctly). I am probably looking at the completely wrong thing however.

Any idea on what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot `KafkaProperties` (e.g. that `spring.kafka.listener.concurrency = 4`) and the mentioned `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` are applied to the `@KafkaListener` components. There is nothing to do with Spring Integration at all. At least automatically.

You need to do that manually:

```
Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaConsumer, ListenerMode.record, "test-topic")
      .configureListenerContainer(c ->
                        c.concurrency(this.kafkaProperties.getListener().getConcurrency()))
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any other listener-properties that should be explicitly set in the same fashion offhand?

Comment: See `KafkaProperties.Listener` class for more properties and `KafkaMessageListenerContainerSpec` for population.

Comment: Sorry, last question for this - some properties (such as no-poll-threshold, or monitor-interval) aren't able to be set using this method. Is there an alternative for those?

Comment: `noPollThreshold` and `monitorInterval` must go to the `ContainerProperties`. See an overloaded `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(ConsumerFactory<K, V> consumerFactory, ContainerProperties containerProperties,
   KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode listenerMode)`

Comment: And therefore your `"test-topic"` must go to that `ContainerProperties` as well.